# edge cover number + matching number = $|V|$

Tags: graph-theory

Given a connected graph $G=(V,E)$, a theorem states that edge covering number + size of a maximum matching = total number of vertices in $G$.

I'm just wondering how I can prove this theorem? The proof was never given in class.

Comment: See the "Graph's  Matching and edge covering" under Related questions (sorry, I can't link on my device)

Comment: Or: "Prove that the sum of minimum edge cover and maximum matching is the vertex count", also under Related